# How to always display at least two decimal places?

Tags: delphi, floating-point, decimal

I need to format the values of a `TFloatField` in order to always display at least two decimal places.

**Example:**

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.234
```

**Output:**

```
1.00
1.20
1.23
1.234
```

I've tried setting the `DisplayFormat` property but when I put too many hashtags (like `0.00###############`) the approximation causes the following undesired output:

```
1,00
1,19999999999999996
1,22999999999999998
1,23399999999999999
```

Comment: Well, you cannot use floats for exact representation. Use a decimals library instead.

Comment: `but when I put too many hashtags (like 0.00###############) the approximation causes the following undesired output`  So... don't put too many "hashtags", then.

Comment: @J... I could agree but... Should I empirically test or is there a rule for determinating a "safe" number of hashtags for hiding the approximation?

Comment: There is no safe way, unless you use another math representation. Best thing you could do is to add another decimal until the error is less than a certain limit.

Comment: @LURD That's not true.  If you use double precision that guarantees 15-17 digits of precision, depending on the number.  Excel truncates at 15 significant figures, for example, because those will always be precise.  Same situation here - limit to 15 sig figs and the output should be correct.

Comment: @J... It's 17 "significant digits", not 17 "precise digits". 1.2 is only 2 digits, yet, it cannot be precisely represented as a double (hence the 1.19999... value). For that level of precision, BCD is needed.

Comment: @KenBourassa I'm saying that if OP does not format to longer than 15 digits, all of those digits will be precise.  1.2 is not exactly representable, but when formatted to 15 digits it will appear as 1.20000000000000.  OP is getting into trouble because they are going to 18 digits, which exceeds the precision of a double.

Comment: @J... It seems you're right, I digged a little bit in the sources and found that `TFloatField.GetAsString` calls `FloatToStr` which in turn calls `FloatToText` passing `15` as value for the `Precision` parameter (`FloatToText(Buffer, Value, fvExtended,
    ffGeneral, 15, 0, AFormatSettings)`)

Comment: @J... "Excel truncates at 15 significant figures, for example, because those will always be precise. Same situation here - limit to 15 sig figs and the output should be correct." This statement is false. Some numbers require more than 15 digits to define them.

Comment: As it happens the Delphi libraries are deficient in that they don't correctly convert between floating point and text. There are mistakes in both directions. To be fair, most language runtimes have got this wrong in the past. However, most language runtimes have corrected these errors in the past 10 years. Delphi's developers have not made any effort to do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you mean that formatting these numbers with 15 zeros/hashtags (`0.00#############`) will display some "undesired" decimal digits?

Comment: Delphi can display incorrect values. Close to the correct values but every so slightly inaccurate

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It will be *precise in those 15 digits*.  You know what I mean.

Comment: @J... I didn't know that was what you meant. However, I'm not 100% sure that this is true. I think Delphi can produce values which are wrong to 1 or 2 ulps.  Myself, I've stopped using the Delphi libraries for this. I use dragon4 and dtoa.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm pretty sure that the first 15 digits represented in a double are always correct (ie: 1 or 2 ulps will never change the 15th digit).  I could be wrong - if so, 14 digits can absolutely always be trusted.  I've not noticed errors in Delphi's float to string conversions, but I've never really cared to that level of precision generally, so I can believe that Delphi's implementation may have bugs.  A double, in principle, has sufficient precision for 15 digits in any case, assuming that the string conversion routine isn't broken.